# URL Redirection Service using AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

My use case is as follows: I'm trying to create a url redirect service (with an "umbrella" hyperlink) based on a user's home country (provided by a federated identity), and looking for a solution using AWS services.  I'm sure there is a relatively simple way to do this in AWS but am not familiar enough with full-stack development and the available options.

I have a lambda function that takes a user's federated identity and returns their home country as an ISO-3166 code. Based on this, I need to set up a hyperlink with a custom domain. When the user clicks on the hyperlink, the site should redirect the user to any number of other URLs based on the home country value provided by the lambda. The mappings for the redirect urls should also be stored somewhere in AWS either in a database, AppConfig, etc, and should be easily changeable.

Since the site itself has no homepage or content of it's own, I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this in AWS.

I'm about to set up a custom domain in Route 53 and not really sure what is the best option from there. I've read about the solutions for domain redirection in Route 53 [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/route-53-redirect-to-another-domain), but since I'm new to these services I'm not sure which would fit my use case best.

I've looked into AWS Amplify hosting for [URL redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html) but it seems like setting up an amplify stack is excessive for the use case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With R53 you can do automatic geolocation or geoproximity routing.
ex. a user is based in Europe and connects to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), you route him to eu.mydomain.com.
It will not be based on his identity and a mapping table, it will be based on his location at the time of the connection.

You can use CloudFront and Lambda@Edge to control which origin the user will hit.
ex. a user connects to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), you route him to a CloudFront distribution, a Lamba@Edge function is triggered in the closest region, extracts the user identity from the headers, check the region associated with this user and route him to [www.mydomain.com/eu](http://www.mydomain.com/eu).
It is wise to replicate or cache the mapping table in all the regions where the Lambda@Edge is executed.

You can also use HTTP redirect, a simpler approach.
ex. a user connects to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), you route him to a Lamba function, extract the user identity from the headers, check the region associated with this user and redirect him to eu.mydomain.com.
No need to replicate the mapping table in this case.